# Show Element Based On Current Selected Menu Item Withing Ng-Repeat in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a navigation bar in an application where I want to show related to a selected nav item image on click. Both navigation items and images located in the same array of objects in controller, however I cannot figure out how to achieve what I want. Could you please review the code below and navigate me to a suitable solution?

HTML

```
<ul id="nav-items">
    <li ng-repeat="n in coreCtrl.navItems">{{n.title}}</li>
</ul>

<ul id="backgrounds">
    <li ng-repeat="i in coreCtrl.navItems" ng-show"some-expression">
        <img ng-src="{{i.bgUrl}}" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

ANGULAR CTRL

```
self.navItems = [
     { title: 'item1', bgUrl: 'img1.jpg' }
   , { title: 'item2', bgUrl: 'img2.jpg' }
   , { title: 'item3', bgUrl: 'img3.jpg' }
   , { title: 'item4', bgUrl: 'img4.jpg' }
   , { title: 'item5', bgUrl: 'img5.jpg' }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, first we need to to make change when clicking the title. So let's add a ng-click

```
<ul id="nav-items">
  <li ng-repeat="n in coreCtrl.navItems" 
      ng-click="coreCtrl.selectedItem=n">{{n.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Then we display the image if the item is the selectedItem.

```
<ul id="backgrounds">
    <li ng-repeat="i in coreCtrl.navItems" ng-show"i===coreCtrl.selectedItem">
        <img ng-src="{{i.bgUrl}}" />
    </li>
</ul>

// Set default selected item in your controller.
self.selectedItem = self.navItems[0];
```

Another very common pattern in this situation is adding an active-class to your menu-item:

```
<ul id="nav-items">
  <li ng-repeat="n in coreCtrl.navItems" 
      ng-click="coreCtrl.selectedItem=n"
      ng-class="{'active':coreCtrl.selectedItem===n}">
    {{n.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a million :) Works perfectly!

Comment: Why background item have ng-repeat, it must be simple li or div, we don't need to load all the image until user select that

Comment: What Ali is referring to is that you can use `<img ng-src="{{coreCtrl.selectedItem.bgUrl}}" />` without a ng-repeat. I made it this way for minimal changes to the code in question. (Also, if you want to load images before use or not is subjective, but I admit there might be better ways to preload images.)

Answer (score 1):

Try making it much more simple:

## HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="n in coreCtrl.navItems">
  <ul id="nav-items">
    <li>{{n.title}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="backgrounds">
    <li ng-show"some-expression">
      <img ng-src="{{n.bgUrl}}" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## Controller

```
self.navItems = [  
  { title: 'item1', bgUrl: 'img1.jpg' },
  { title: 'item2', bgUrl: 'img2.jpg' },
  { title: 'item3', bgUrl: 'img3.jpg' },
  { title: 'item4', bgUrl: 'img4.jpg' },
  { title: 'item5', bgUrl: 'img5.jpg' }
];
```